# How to deal with optimistic locking failure in GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I get optimistic locking failure error when our system comes under heavy load, dozens of concurrent transactions. Application is load balanced over multiple servers communicating with a single database instance.

I understand that at the core of this is GORM optimistic locking mechanism. New thread changes domain object property while it is loaded in original thread and change attempted.

If so, what would be the best way to deal with it? I do not want to have to handle the error because rolling the entire transaction back is not a good solution for.

What are my options?

1. Declaring version false? Would that prevent optimistic locking on that domain object and allow concurrent threads to change it, even if that means overwriting one another without an error?
2. Locking domain object for the duration of the transaction by retrieving it with Object.lock(id)? How significant would be a performance hit, hard to say without testing, but is this the best way to go about it?
3. Any other options?

Relevant code included below. If locking is the best way to do it, how do I accomplish it since Object is accesses as child from unsaved parent object?

That line #390 in ProductOrderService.

```
private rollbackInventory(Order order) {
    order.items.each {orderItem->
        Product product = orderItem.product
        product.increaseQuantityBy(orderItem.qty)
        product.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

And increaseQuantityBy method in Product domain class looks like this:

```
.......

Integer qty

.......

public void increaseQuantityBy(Integer change) {
    changeQuantityBy(change)
}

public void decreaseQuantityBy(Integer change) {
    changeQuantityBy(-change)
}

private void changeQuantityBy(Integer change) {
    qty += change
}
```

This is the error:

```
2016-04-29 08:08 -- ERROR-grails.app.controllers.com.shop.order.ProductOrderController:Exception occurred. Object of class [com.shop.Product] with identifier [5774]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.shop.Product#5774]
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [com.shop.Product] with identifier [5774]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.shop.Product#5774]
        at com.shop.order.ProductOrderService$_rollbackInventory_closure5.doCall(ProductOrderService.groovy:390)
        at com.shop.order.ProductOrderService.rollbackInventory(ProductOrderService.groovy:387)
        at com.shop.order.ProductOrderService.processOrder(ProductOrderService.groovy:178)
        at com.shop.order.ProductOrderController.order(ProductOrderController.groovy:240)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.shop.Product#5774]
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: You need to narrow down your question. We, are not free software consultants. Having said that, conceptually I recommend treating the credit card processing and the inventory changes as a single transaction. There's nothing in Grails that will do this for you, as this is beyond the scope of GORM/Hibernate transactions. So you'd have to roll your own transactional system on top of GORM and the payments processor. Conceptual questions like this are better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa thank you for your response. I apologize if I gave you impression that I treat Stackoverlow community as a pool of free software consultants. That's who you speak for, I presume, when you say "we", you mean the entire community here. In regards to my question, its outlined under "What are my options?"  for example, very software specific question: "Declaring version false and dropping it from Product table? Would that prevent optimistic locking and eliminate errors?" conceptual.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa to clarify my question further, I will remove any context specific remarks. You can let me know if this makes more sense and no longer gives you an impression of being treated like a free software consultant.